# Chrome extension - Content script not sending response (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So i'm making a google chrome extension, and i'm having some issues with the messaging system.

I made a messaging function that allows you to send a message to a content script or background script by defining it in the arguments, this function is in the popup script.

My problem is that when the content script sends a response, the popup script will see it as undefined.

This is my code:

**popup Script:**

```
// The messaging function
function passMessage(message, location){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

        //Send the message to a content script or background?
        switch (location){
            case "content":
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {popupMessage: message}, function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
                break;

            case "background":
                chrome.extension.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {popupMessage: message}, function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
                break;
        }

    });
}



// Call the function like so:
var x = passMessage( "Hello world!" , "content" );

// Undefined (Should be "Hi popup!")
console.log( x );
```

**content script:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.popupMessage == "Hello world!"){ 
        // Logs "Hello world!"
        console.log(request.popupMessage); 

        // Should send "Hi popup!" back.
        sendResponse("Hi popup!"); 
    }
});
```

So basically everything works perfectly besides the response.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Sending messages are asyncronous, so return is unnecessary. Change "return response" to console.log(response). You should also log timestamps to see and understand that log x is evaluated first.

Comment: @SkalárWag Hm, would there be any way of returning the value of the response? The reasoning for this is that I want my script to peform certain actions when getting a specific reply.

Comment: Sure, place your TODO code in the inner curly brackets (into the callback function), instead of return. This is how asynchronous method works.